# Passing Parameters in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

I have implemented a GUI using javafx in a class called "Gui" which extends apllication. I have a seperate class which handles the logic called "Logic". I want to pass an instance of "Logic" class to to "Gui" class. Is there anyway that I can create an instance of "Gui" class before calling "Application.launch()" in main method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not easily, and this is almost always the wrong way to approach this. In particular, you don't even know that the `main(...)` method will be invoked: in Java 8 a JavaFX application is launched by the JVM without (necessarily) calling `main(...)` at all.

You should really consider the `start(...)` method in your `Application` subclass as the equivalent of the `main(...)` method in a regular Java application; in other words, think of this as your application entry point and create the `Logic` instance there.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. I will start over.